# Certain elements display smaller in Safari on Mac?

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

After fiddling around with an issue I am having I have come to this conclusion:

my list Elements are displaying smaller in Safari on my Macbook than they are on Safari on my PC. IE, and Firefox are displaying properly also.

What might be causing this difference? It is hindering my ability to complete this design.

www.christopherbier.com/gbg

Please let me know if there are any css tags that might be causing this.

Here is my previous question that includes my css etc. [CSS spacing issues with Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731546/css-spacing-issues-with-safari)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider including css reset stylesheet. You can find a good one here:

[YUI CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

This basically "removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default styling of HTML elements, creating a level playing field across A-grade browsers".

Hopefully that will solve your problem!

Comment: I always start a design with a reset CSS, and my current reset.css is based on the YUI one. Eric Meyer's version is also worth pointing out: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it may well not be a css tag that's causing the issue, but just a difference in defaults on the two different browser versions.  Each version is probably tailored to the OS to some extent, and may look different, which is expected.

Overriding this default behavior should raise a warning flag, because you're changing the overall look and feel, and it may not match well with the OS layout in general.  It doesn't mean don't do it, but it does mean that you might want to proceed with caution.

Comment: It is a major flaw, and I feel that it is a common one. I am able to get it to line up now, but the width of the "asseen" bar is not covering the whole space as it is in other browsers. Do you have any idea why this might be occuring?